# sencha touch insert data to localstorage

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

Hi i have found a lot of examples about loading data from a db in sencha.
i try to make a list with notes and on second step i want to be able to add(save) a note to my db. i try that on localstorage.

for now i load data from a array in my Arraystore. 
where shall i set my proxy? (in store or in model?)

how could i insert data in my store?
i have tried something like that on my current arraystore but with no luck:
(this is the code run by pressing a code):

```
 MyArrayStore.add({title:"newnote",narrative:"bla bla bla",date:now,id:noteid});
    MyArrayStore.sync();
```

the browser console gets an error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: MyArrayStore is not defined
shall i make an instance of my store or something?

my model is this:
thanx for the answer. i try that on architect.
my model is this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.NoteModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    alias: 'model.NoteModel',
    config: {
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'id',
                type: 'int'
            },
            {
                name: 'date',
                type: 'date'
            },
            {
                name: 'title',
                type: 'string'
            },
            {
                name: 'narrative',
                type: 'string'
            }
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'localstorage',
            id: 'local'
        }
    }
});
```

and my store is this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyArrayStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: [
        'MyApp.model.NoteModel'
    ],

    config: {
        data: [
            {
                title: 'Note 1',
                narrative: 'test1 1'
            },
            {
                title: 'Note 2',
                narrative: 'narrative 2'
            },
            {
                title: '3 ertyyh',
                narrative: 'narrative 3'
            },
            {
                title: '4 asdf',
                narrative: 'narrative 4'
            },
            {
                title: 'Note 5',
                narrative: 'narrative 5'
            },
            {
                title: 'weadf',
                narrative: 'narrative 6'
            }
        ],
        model: 'MyApp.model.NoteModel',
        storeId: 'MyArrayStore'
    }
});
```

Comment: i tried something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068585/insert-in-sencha-touch-data-store but still .add is not working

Comment: i also try that on json file. i still can load data, but how can i work with jsonWriter to write data on my json file??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set your proxy in your model OR in your store.
Here's how to do it within your model.

```
Ext.define('MyModel', {

extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

config: {
    fields: ['field1'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'localstorage',
        id  : 'my-model-localstorage-id'
    }
});
```

The same can alternatively be done in your store.

After that, given that 'MyArrayStore' is an instance of such a store, the code you propose should work just fine.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanx for the answer. i try that on architect. i ll update my question by inserting my model and store.

Comment: must i create an instance of my store? my data of the store are already loaded by my listview so i assume that the store is already created. am i wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access your store (the one you updated in your question), then you can use:

```
Ext.StoreManager.get('MyArrayStore')
```

So, for instance, the operations you wanted to perform could be done in the following way:

```
var store=Ext.StoreManager.get('MyArrayStore');
store.add({title:"newnote",narrative:"bla bla bla",date:now,id:noteid});
store.sync();
```

Comment: thanx that worked!
so i have to access my store by Storemanager?

Comment: Indeed. At least, that is how I do it and I am not aware of other ways to acces your stores.